# Paralax-style scrolling, user can scroll only one slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using ScrollTo plugin to create a simple paralax-style page-changing. Here is what happens when you scroll

```
var location = window.location.hash;
    if(location == '') { var location = '#home' }   // Default location

    slides = ['#home', '#about', '#characters'];    // All the slides in an array

    // Calculating previous and next slides
    var currentEl = slides.indexOf(location);
    var prevEl = currentEl - 1;
    var nextEl = currentEl + 1;

    if(delta > 0)
    {   
        if(location != '#home')
        {
            gofor(slides[prevEl]);  // Scrolling up
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(location != '#characters')
        {
            gofor(slides[nextEl]);  // Scrolling down
        }
    }

});
```

And here is the gofor function itself.

```
function gofor(slide)
{
    $(slide).clearQueue().ScrollTo({duration: 700});    // Scrolling to the given slide
    $('.nav>a').removeClass('active');          // Removing all active classes
$(slide + '_nav').addClass('active');       // Updating the menu class with the _nav suffix id
window.location.hash = slide;               // Updating the location.hash with the new position
```

}

This is working okay but when you scroll your wheel more than one step it goes more than one page forward. How can i stop the scrolling function for a certain amount of time (like 3 seconds) and then let the mouse regain its scrolling function again?

Thanks.